# Angular 5: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Tags: angular5, angular-components

Error:
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined**

I had comic component, was working fine, but I decided to make a child component, and now it's not working.
I have a parent component 'comics', and a child component 'pagination'. The comics are displayed fine, but the pagination is not working.

In the code, the `console.log(this.pagination);` is returning an array like ('offset': 20, 'count':1)

But pagination.component.html ir returning an error `Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined` so pagination is empty, has no data. So parent comics.component.ts is not sharing this variable with child.

I tried to declare `pagination: Pagination;` in pagination.component.ts but pagination is still empty.

So I think I'm declaring something in a wrong mode, or I should declare something I'm not declaring. I searched, and I tried to find what's missing but I did not find anything and it's still not working.

my code:

```
// file: pagination.ts

export class Pagination {
  offset: number;
  count: number;
}



// file: /comics/comics.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Comic } from '../comic';
import { Pagination } from '../pagination';
import { ComicService } from '../comic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comics',
  templateUrl: './comics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comics.component.css']
})
export class ComicsComponent implements OnInit {

  comics: Comic;
  pagination: Pagination;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private comicService: ComicService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getComics(): void {
    const offset = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('offset');
    this.comicService.getComics(offset, 20)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.comics = result['data']['results'];
        console.log(this.comics);

        this.pagination.offset = result['data']['offset'];
        this.pagination.count = result['data']['count'];

        console.log(this.pagination);
  }
);
  }
}


// file: /pagination/pagination.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Pagination } from '../pagination';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.css']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


// file: comics/comics.component.html

<div *ngFor="let comic of comics">
  <h5>{{comic.title | uppercase}} </h5>
</div>

<app-pagination></app-pagination>



// file: pagination/pagination.component.html

<div>
  <h5>{{pagination.offset}}</h5>
  <span>{{pagination.count}}</span>
</div>
```

Versions used:

> Angular CLI: 1.7.3
>
> Node: 8.9.4
>
> OS: darwin x64
>
> Angular: 5.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these two components are in a parent-child relationship, your best option is to simply define `offset` and `count` as input properties for the child component, and pass them from the parent, like this:

**comics.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Comic } from '../comic';
import { Pagination } from '../pagination';
import { ComicService } from '../comic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comics',
  templateUrl: './comics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comics.component.css']
})
export class ComicsComponent implements OnInit {

  comics: Comic;
  offset;
  count;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private comicService: ComicService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getComics(): void {
    const offset = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('offset');
    this.comicService.getComics(offset, 20)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.comics = result['data']['results'];
        console.log(this.comics);

        this.offset = result['data']['offset'];
        this.count = result['data']['count'];
  }
);
  }
}
```

**pagination.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Pagination } from '../pagination';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.css']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() offset;
  @Input() count;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**comics.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let comic of comics">
  <h5>{{comic.title | uppercase}} </h5>
</div>

<app-pagination [offset]="offset" [count]="count"></app-pagination>
```

**pagination.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h5>{{offset}}</h5>
  <span>{{count}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works so I will accept it as the good solution, but this was not the error. For some reason I could not set information to the pagination object  in the parent component. I solved it with an array with the same architecture as pagination object in the parent, and passing it to the child, the child has the pagination object and inherits it from the parent array.
Your solution is good, but in pagination object I have a lot of information (I simplified it only for asking) and I prefer to pass one object than pass 10 string variables. Though your message helped me a lot.